# Draggable markerin mapbox/dcc.Graph component

Tags: javascript, python, mapbox, plotly-dash

I have a mapbox in a dcc.graph component set to a specific location, is there a way that I can now lock the map in place and make the marker draggable within that fixed window. Below is my current code.

```
   html.Div(
    style = {
        'display': 'block',
        'background-color': 'white',
        'border-radius': '20px',
        'width': '100%',
        'margin-left': '0%',
    },
    children = [
        dcc.Store(id='marker-store', data={'lon': -95.45647282221269, 'lat': 29.646081571785604}),
        html.Div(
            children = [
                dcc.Graph(
                    id='map-graph',
                    figure={
                        'data': [{
                            'lat': [29.646081571785604],
                            'lon': [-95.45647282221269],
                            'type': 'scattermapbox',
                            'mode': 'markers',
                            'marker': {'size': 20, 'color': 'red'}
                        }],
                        'layout': {
                            'mapbox': {
                                'accesstoken': mapbox_access_token,
                                'style': 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-streets-v11',
                                'center': {'lat': 29.646081571785604, 'lon': -95.45647282221269},
                                'zoom': 17,
                            },
                            'dragmode': 'pan',
                            'autosize': True,
                            'hovermode': 'closest'
                        }
                    },
                    config={'scrollZoom': False}
                ),
                dragnode.DragNode(
                    id='marker',
                    children=html.Div(
                        style={
                            'position': 'absolute',
                            'top': '0',
                            'left': '0',
                            'width': '20px',
                            'height': '20px',
                            'border-radius': '50%',
                            'background-color': 'blue'
                        }
                    ),
                    nodeData={
                        'x': -95.45647282221269,
                        'y': 29.646081571785604
                    },
                    onDragData=lambda pos: {'lon': pos['x'], 'lat': pos['y']},
                    style={'position': 'absolute', 'zIndex': '999'}
                )
            ],
        ),
    ],
),

@dash.callback(
    Output('buildPageLongitude', 'value'),
    Output('buildPageLatitude', 'value'),
    [
        Input('map-graph', 'clickData'),
    ],
    [
        State('map-graph', 'figure')
    ],
)
def update_marker(click_data, figure):
    if click_data is not None:
        lat = click_data['points'][0]['lat']
        lon = click_data['points'][0]['lon']
        figure['data'][0]['lat'] = [lat]
        figure['data'][0]['lon'] = [lon]
    return [lon, lat]
```

I want to lock the frame in position and be able to drag the marker around within this window. is this possible?